# Admin Panel Development

Tags: admin

How to create Tab on Admin Panel like "General Settings" screenshot ?

How to create List on Admin Panel like "Pages" screenshot ?

[image: General Settings]

[image: Pages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This would be a good place to start. [`add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/).
2. The posts list are automatically created when you register a new CPT. You can, however, create anything in a custom menu page (read the docs from point 1).